mermaid graph, stacking nodes on top of each other (R .qmd file)
I have the following mermaid code:
mermaid("
graph TD
    subgraph L3 Countries
        B[Russia]
        C[United Kingdom]
    end
    subgraph L2 Schools
        D[School 1]
        E[School 2]
        F[School 3]
        G[School 4]
    end

    B --> D
    B --> E
    C --> F
    C --> G
")

creating:

I'd like to make the schools stack on top of each other, like this:


Using Mermaid.live I came close to what you're asking. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to control the arrows as you have depicted in your drawing.
graph TD
subgraph Countries
    B[Russia]
    C[United Kingdom]
end

subgraph Schools
direction TB
    D[School 1]
    E[School 2]
    F[School 3]
    G[School 4]
end

B --> D
D --> E
C --> F
F --> G



thanks, this is getting closer, but the hierarchy is between UK and School3 and UK and school4, so the arrow needs to come from UK in both cases. I have a lot of schools, so I don't want them horizontally

Ok, I understand the requirement now. This version is not perfect but with some more fine tuning it might work. I found that you can use invisible lines to 'persuade' Mermaid to layout the nodes. With some more experimenting you should be able to get things positioned as you want them.
graph TB

subgraph Countries
 A[Russia]
 C[United Kingdom]
end

subgraph Schools
    subgraph rschools[ ]
        D[School 1]
        E[School 2]
        H[School 3]
        I[School 4]
        J[School 5]
        JJ[School 16]
    end
    subgraph ukschools[ ]
        F[School 6]
        G[School 7]
        K[School 8]
        L[School 9]
        M[School 10]
        N[School 11]
        O[School 12]
        P[School 13]
        Q[School 14]
        R[School 15]
    end
end

A --- D
A --- E
A --- H
A --- I
A --- J
A --- JJ
D ~~~ H
E ~~~ J
H ~~~ JJ
E ~~~ JJ

C --- F
C --- G
C --- K
C --- L
C --- M
C --- N
C --- O
C --- P
C --- Q
C --- R
F ~~~ N
G ~~~ O
K ~~~ P
L ~~~ Q
F ~~~ R


